# Inserting data from one table to other but don't want the primary id

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I am trying to copy data from one table to another table but I don't want to have the ID column copied into the the new table.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
INSERT INTO T2 (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) 
(SELECT AUTO, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, 
 FROM T1);
```

When the table T2 was created the ID was not set to auto-increment since the IDs are going to be generated by the front end app going forward.

Don't know if this has been asked before but please help.

Comment: See : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/moving-tables-to-another-sql2008-database-including-indexes-triggers-etc

You can achieve your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO T2 (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) 
(
   SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS rn,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, 
   FROM T1, (SELECT @row:=0) r
);
```

check the query at SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91037/1

Comment: If I skip the ID column it will throw an error - "ID cannot be null"

Comment: Ok got it, let me give a another solution in a moment